# 64-bit and 32-bit C++ executables with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, 32bit-64bit

I have an executable compiled on a 64-bit machine using Code::Blocks and GCC compiler. I also have someone on a 32-bit machine that can't run the executable. Do I need to make two separate versions of the executable, or is there a way that I can compile it to run on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use -m32 in gcc command line to build a 32-bit version. Please make sure your code is portable from 64-bit to 32-bit.

Comment: So there's no way to make an executable run on both 32 and 64 bit then?

Comment: @josh Well most 32-bit programs will run in 64-bit environments (obviously.) The problem probably lies in you linking against 64-bit libraries or using a 64-bit compiler. Unless you have 64-bit specific code, it should be fine as long as your target is a 32-bit machine.

Comment: I work on a rhel 6 and there 32bit executable could run on a 64bit OS. You need test on your platform.

Comment: @remyabel Thank you, I think I know what I need to do now.